# Can i use hBase's checkAndPut() in Mapper/Reducer Application?

Tags: hbase

I would like to use `put()` in the `Reducer` if column condition is satisfied.

So i found `checkAndPut` method. But `table` instance doesn't exist in `reduce` method.

Can i use `checkAndPut` method in HBase Reducer?
Or Is there any other way to use `put()` in the `reduce` method only when column conditions are satisfied?
(Mapper's source table is different from Reducer's target table)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use checkAndPut in Reducer of any MapReduce job. You need to have an instance or instantiate HTable and then use [checkandput](https://hbase.apache.org/2.0/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html#doCheckAndPut-byte:A-byte:A-byte:A-java.lang.String-byte:A-org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.TimeRange-org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put-)